# New laptop recommendations

Tags: laptop

So... I am buying a new laptop and I could use some recommendations.

**What i am looking for:**

- good keyboard and trackpad (this is very important for me)
- at least 4-core i7 processor
- any graphic card which is better than the usual Intel HD Graphics XXXX (maybe something in the range of Radeon R7 M370)
- not bigger than 15 inch
- under or just over 1000usd

**What I mean by good keyboard:**

I am a MacBook user so I am used to the feel of their keyboard and super responsive multitouch trackpad. I've been told that Lenovo laptops also have some of the best keyboards on the market. Therefore I am looking somewhere in this direction. (also, backlight would be great)

**What I have found so far:**

- Lenovo ThinkPad E560 (would be ideal if it had 4-core i7 processor)
- Lenovo IdeaPad Y700 (good, but a liitle expensive)

Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

The Lenovo Y50 meets all of the criteria you mentioned.  It has a low profile Island style backlit keyboard, a large multi touch trackpad, comes available with quad core i7 CPUs and gaming capable Nvidia GTX graphics cards.  They start at around 800USD for those options, but can be found a little cheaper as they are recently a discontinued model.  They can also be found with touch screens or UHD displays.  However, the size is 15.6''. This is an industry standard, to go smaller would be impractical but possible if it is a necessity.

My other suggestion with be a MSI gaming laptop.  The GE and GS series come in 15.6'' and have high quality components in all models, suitable for intensive usage.  The keyboard that you would want is the SteelSeries, it is also a low profile and very responsive keyboard, available with multi color backlighting if you desire.  These can be had for right around 1000 USD depending again on configuration.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend the Lenovo IdeaPad Y700 to you as it is an amazing laptop for the price; [Newegg sells it](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834321438) for around $1,000.

- CPU:  i7 6700HQ.
- RAM: 16 GB DDR4.
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M.
- STORAGE: 1 TB HDD + 128 GB SSD.

It has the latest Skylake processor, DDR4 RAM, a decent GPU (roughly equivalent to the desktop 750Ti) and an SSD. It also has a backlit keyboard and a 15.6" Full HD display.